# How can I test different versions of the same codebase?

Tags: git, testing, design-patterns

This is a design question, quite deep, so I'll try to explain it to my best. It can be valid for any programming language.

We have a codebase in a language. Let's say it's an app that is versioned using [server](https://semver.org) and that it's tracked using [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) for the sake of the example.

**Let's say we find a bug in the version `1.5.2`, a developer is tasked with fixing it and a version `1.5.3` is created**

Normally in a savvy organization, regression tests are enforced. This means that there is a test that proves that from `1.5.3` onwards that bug can't occur again, under the same circumstances.

Nowadays I see the code change and I see the fix and a test that goes to the path of the fix. If the buggy code has changed. How can I see that the version `1.5.2` was failing? As a reviewer, how do I know that the code change did change it without just running the code in my head?

Yeah we could have tests checked out in a different repo / history and run git-bisect. That is useful. But, is there a technique or strategy to test 2 different versions of the repo without involving git, in the same codebase?

Comment: The developer commits a test that fails, then commits a code change that makes the test pass. The reviewer is free to walk back to HEAD~1 and verify the failure before approving the PR.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to think of ways that say the same by just reading the source